# Start x axis at minimum value

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to set the start of drawing column data from a minimum value, but cannot figure out how to do this. That is, that the axis starts with a value of -43, and not with 0 (see screenshots).

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0DY5.png)

I want to get something like this:

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5njrb.png)

```
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      return `${moment(this.x).format('MMM DD')}: ${this.y.toFixed(2)}`;

    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointStart: -50,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.y:.2f}'
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
      zIndex: 1,
      color: '#5c5c5c',
      value: 0,
      width: 3,
    }],
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth : 1,
    labels: {
      formatter() {
        return moment(this.value).format('MMM DD');
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: [...this.monthData.resultByDays.map(res => [res.date, res.result])],
    type: 'column'
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good approach will be to use the columnrange series rather than basic column. In the columnrange it is possible to set the range where the point could start from.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ur6qgnbz/

And the code to hide the '-60' data label:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter() {
    if(this.y === -60) {
        return false
    } else {
        return this.y
    }
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.columnrange